# Is it possible to configure more than 3 timers using setitimer?

Tags: c, linux, timer

How can I configure more than 3 timers using setitimer? The linux man page says "The system provides each process with three interval timers, each decrementing in a distinct time domain. When any timer expires, a signal is sent to the process, and the timer (potentially) restarts" .

Answer (score 2):

You are limited to three with the itimer mechanism.  See `timerfd_create()` for a more modern replacement (albeit linux-only) which doesn't have this limitation.  It also works on a file descriptor instead of signals, so can be more easily integrated with event loops implemented with select/poll.

Answer (score 2):

Linux offers `timer_create` (since 2.6) to make new interval timers: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/timer_create.2.html.

If you find yourself using a system that has only the basic timers, you can always create your own in a user-written library.

There is also `timerfd_create` (also Linux-specific).

Comment: `timer_create` is in POSIX and also available on some other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `mod` check on a single timer to abstract it out to many timers. This is how google handles their multiple timers in javascript and I would assume it could work here too. The reasoning is that it is **orders of magnitudes faster** than running multiple timers consecutively.

In other words, if you have a timer which runs ever 5ms, and you had a count of how many times it had run, then you could `mod` that count and every 10 of those would be a 50ms timer as well.

Comment: So what if you have one timer that needs to run at 19997 Hz and another that needs to run at 15101 Hz? :-)

Comment: @R.. - Good question. If you needed to have prime number support for timing you would overlap two timers which run at 2 and 3 second intervals. Any prime number can be broken into a combination of 2s and 3s.

Comment: @TravisJ: could you explain a bit more? I'm not quite sure that i got the concept correct

Comment: There's no way you can get a 19997 Hz expiration from 2 timers whose expirations are 2 and 3 seconds...